# How do I change the user Windows 8 automatically logs in with?

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot

After doing a Windows Update, my computer is booting to the "hidden administrator" account which I had activated to take care of an issue.  I prefer to boot into the standard administrator account, and don't know why it isn't.

Any assistance?  Thanks very much.

Comment: To make this more general and applicable to more users might I suggest changing the question to read "How do I change the user Windows 8 automatically logs in with?"  You can keep your details obviously.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [netplwiz](http://www.howtogeek.com/112919/how-to-make-your-windows-8-computer-logon-automatically/).  Just run it from search and you'll be able to set your default auto-login user.

Make sure *Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer* is unchecked then click "ok"

A dialog box should popup asking for the username and password of the account you want to have auto-login.  If it's a microsoft account make sure you use the full email address as the username.

Note, you may need to *check* the box if it's already unchecked, close the dialog, and start from step 1.

As an aside, you should probably disable auto-login anyway.  It stores your password in the registry in plain text which isn't exactly secure...

Comment: How do you activate auto-login?

Comment: @user308075 I improved my answer a bit with more details and a better link with pictures.  Hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: Hmm.  It's still asking for a password, but at least it's booting to the HomeGroup user account now.